# Lattice in Barry lyndon

Tags: barry-lyndon

When Barry meets Captain Feeney at an Inn in Kubrick's movie, there's a wooden lattice hanging on the side.  Does anyone know what it is for?

[image]

Comment: My first instinct is the hanging lattice is a sign indicating that the inn has vacancy - in other words, it has rooms available. Interesting question that I hope to research further.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the phrase "Red Lattice" is an obsolete one meaning "**relating to an alehouse**".

Apparently used in a some of Shakespeare's plays including *The Merry Wives of Windsor* ([**Google Books**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Koo5AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=shakespeare+red+lattice&source=bl&ots=dpg632Gsxq&sig=Lj8244ucynOf-Eo617gu3_71xWg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj61Oygq5TRAhWnKMAKHZaiApgQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=shakespeare%20red%20lattice&f=false)) and ([**Google Books again**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HLfPAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA590&lpg=PA590&dq=inn+signs+red+lattice&source=bl&ots=zYYu6UhP5r&sig=iyifBkFpRc4JuFZNTG9ZNQkJe88&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFr_CGq5TRAhULBcAKHe6rB_s4ChDoAQgbMAE#v=onepage&q=inn%20signs%20red%20lattice&f=false))

Over time, this has been reduced to just a plain lattice, a painting of a lattice and, in some cases, the word has been misused into "lettuce".